# Initialize array of various length tuples?

Tags: initialization, julia

I have an array `b = [1, 2, 1, 4]`. These values can change. I need to create a `SharedArray` of `Tuples` each with `b[i]` `Int`s.

In other words, if I have `b = [1, 2, 1, 4]` I need:

`x = SharedArray{Tuple{Int}, Tuple{Int,Int}, Tuple{Int}, Tuple{Int,Int,Int,Int}}`

I can't for the life of me figure out how. Any ideas?

Comment: After reading a bit I thought that maybe something along the line `SharedArray(Tuple{Vararg{Int64}},10)` might work, but it doesn't. The error message *ArgumentError: type of SharedArray elements must be bits types, got Tuple{Vararg{Int64,N}}* suggests that there is a chance that this is not possible. But this is only a guess. A solution might be to create a normal `SharedArray` of ints and *encode* what you want. So the layout looks in your case like `[b[1], v11, b[2], v21,, v22, b[3], v31, b[4], v41, v42, v43, v44]`, but that's only a hackaround.

Answer (score 1):

A `SharedArray` can only contain bits types, which a `Tuple` of `Vararg` is not... but here's a draft of @halirutan's idea of encoding the tuples into a flat array:

```
immutable SharedThing{T}
  data::SharedArray{T}
  strides::Vector{Int}
end

function SharedThing{T}(tuples::Tuple{Vararg{T}}...)
  strides = collect(map(length, tuples))
  data = SharedArray(T, sum(strides))
  i = 1
  for (s, t) in zip(strides, tuples)
    data[i:i+s-1] = collect(t)
    i += s
  end
  SharedThing{T}(data, strides)
end

function Base.getindex{T}(xs::SharedThing{T}, i)
  before = sum(xs.strides[1:i-1]) 
  tuple(xs.data[before+1:before + xs.strides[i]]...)
end
```

So:

```
julia> xs = SharedThing((1, 2,3), (22, 33))
SharedThing{Int64}([1,2,3,22,33],[3,2])

julia> xs[1]
(1,2,3)

julia> xs[2]
(22,33)
```

Of course, this is optimizable, does not pay attention to getting a good sharing structure for parallelism, and I also fear that its type handling is suboptimal... still, it can hopefully serve you as a basis.

Comment: A `Tuple` of `Ints` *is* a bits type, at least in 0.5. I cannot use this solution as I need to create separate contiguous arrays to be pointed to by a `ccall`. When I've tried a similar structure, I got segfaults. I'm guessing the created `SharedArray` was not contiguous.

Comment: Ok, right, but a `Vararg` is not a bitstype. Anyway, I don't acutally know much about shared arrays, I just gave it a try -- sorry if it didn't help.

Comment: This will be very helpful to others that come across this with less rigid requirements. Thanks!